# Django Form Preview

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to use django's FormPreview and I can't get it to work properly.  Here's my code:

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
   status = forms.TypedChoiceField(
                                coerce=int, choices=LIST_STATUS, label="type",
                                widget=forms.RadioSelect
                                )
    description = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)
    stage = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, useradd=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['firm'].label = "Firm"
class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    fields =    ['status', 'description', 'stage']


class MyFormPreview(FormPreview):
    form_template = 'templates/post.html'
    preview_template = 'templates/review.html'

    def process_preview(self, request, cleaned_data):
        print "processed"

    def done(self, request, cleaned_data):
        print "done"
        # Do something with the cleaned_data, then redirect
        # to a "success" page.
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

urls.py

```
(r'^post/$', MyFormPreview(MyForm)),
```

post.html

```
<form id = "post_ad" action = "" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <table>
     {{form.as_table}}
     </table>    
 <input type="submit" name="save" value="Post" />
 </form>
```

When I go to /post/ I get the correct form and I fill it out.  When I submit the form it goes right back to /post/ but but there are no errors (I've tried displaying {{errors}}) and the form is empty.  None of my print statements execute.  I'm not sure what I'm missing. Can anyone help me out?  I can't find any documentation besides what's on the django site.

Also, what's the "preview" variable called that I should use in my preview.html template?  {{preview}} or do I just do {{form}} again? -- Answered below.

I tried adding 'django.contrib.formtools' to my installed_apps in settings and I tried using the code from the default form templates from django.contrib as suggested below.  Still, when I submit the form I go right back to the post template, none of my print statements execute :(

Comment: have you tried adding {{ form.non_field_errors }} ?

Comment: That doesn't display anything in my post template either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See django/contrib/formtools/templates for the default templates.

Comment: Thanks for the location of the templates, very helpful.  Any ideas on why I can't get to the preview screen after I submit?  Does my submit button need to be named something specific or maybe my form?

Comment: I found error. you must delete useradd=None. value of useradd not pass to __init__ and useradd recieve data(QueryDict) from form(it must pass to super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)). sorry for my english

Comment: Evgecyn, you're absolutely correct.  I removed the "useradd=None" argument and it started working.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Formtools has been removed from 1.8+ of Django.**

Now accessible at the Github page: [Django-Formtools](https://github.com/django/django-formtools/) and its related documentation can be found at [read the docs](http://django-formtools.readthedocs.org/).

`sudo pip install django-formtools` should help you through getting it installed.

The removal was announced in the [1.8 release highlights](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#removal-of-django-contrib-formtools)